# Protocol constraint Equatable in Swift with ReactiveSwift map function

Tags: swift, protocols, equatable, reactive-swift

I am using `ReactiveSwift`. There are two protocols: `CommonProtocol` and `SpecificProtocol`.
When I use `SpecificProtocol` in `map` function there is an error **Type 'any SpecificProtocol' cannot conform to 'Equatable'**. However it is perfectly fine with using `ConreateItem`

```
protocol CommonProtocol {}

protocol SpecificProtocol: CommonProtocol, Equatable

extension SpecificProtocol where Self: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool { return true }
}

class ConreateItem: SpecificProtocol{}

var messages = MutableProperty<[CommonProtocol]?>(nil)

messages.producer
//  .map({ $0 as? [ConreateItem] }) //that is ok
    .map({ $0 as? [any SpecificProtocol] })//Type 'any SpecificProtocol' cannot conform to'Equatable'
    .skipRepeats()
```

I don't understand why/how `SpecificProtocol` is converted to `any SpecificProtocol`. And what is the correct way to implement `Equatable` constraint on protocol so I could use it in `map` function (`Equatable` is required for high order function in my case)
`map` is of `ReactiveSwift`

Comment: I did some changes on my original question. I found out that error occurs due to skipRepeats that relys on Equatable items. However it is still not clear for me why it says that any SpecificProtocol cannot confirm to Equatable while it really confirms

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr `==` in `Equatable` requires both parameters to be of the same concrete type. This cannot be determined if the compiler only knows that each of the two instances is `any Equatable`.

Without looking too closely at `skipNil()` it looks like it needs a sequence of objects that conform to `Equatable`. `SpecificProtocol` does not declare conformance to `Equatable`, it just declares a function `==` (which has a compiler error because it does not return a `Bool`), so there is a type error.

By the way, note that protocols are not types in Swift which is why the "any" is there. It's short for "anything whose type conforms to `SpecificProtocol`". At some point in the future, you'll have to write `any` explicitly in your declarations. e.g. `[any SpecificProtocol]`

To make SpecificProtocol instances conform to `Equatable` you need

```
protocol SpecificProtocol: CommonProtocol, Equatable
{
...
}
```

You can keep the extension to define a default `==` function or allow concrete types to define their own implementations of it.

**Update**

The reason you see the error message even with `SpecificProtocol` conforming to `Equatable` is because instances of arbitrary types that both conform to `Equatable` cannot be compared for equality. `"foo" == 3` is not allowed even though `String` and `Int` are both equatable.

In order for the array that you return from `map` to be Equatable, it must be able to compare its elements against the elements of another array of the same type and if you know nothing about the elements except they both conform to `SpecificProtocol` you can't compare them for equality because `Equatable` conformance requires both parameters of `==` to be of the same *concrete* type.

Also, I don't think your map closure should be returning an array. I think it should look like `.map({ $0 as? any SpecificProtocol })`

Comment: Thank you for answer! It is clear what any means in this context for me at least now. There is nothing related to any/some keywords that comes together with protocols from Swit 5.7 in my case. I forget to mention that I also tried to make SpecificProtocol to comfirm Equatable. So I added about that into my question. It changes nothing. And commenting skipNil() gives the same result, error occurs on map

Comment: Another thing that makes me stick why it says that any cannot SpecificProtocol confirm Equatable meanwhile I constrained Self by Equatable. It means that any class that confirms SpecificProtocol has Equatable instance, doesn't it?

Comment: And small question regarding the error: should I interpret it as that there might some instance  that did not confirm to Equatable so that compiler blocks me to keep me away from runtime error?

Comment: @Riddik on your last comment: yes. I'm not sure what it is because I don't know ReactSwift very well.

Comment: @Riddik you don't need `where Self: Equatable` in the extension now that `SpecificProtocol` requires conformance to `Equatable`.

Comment: @Riddik I've figured out the real reason for the error. See the update.